# Написать программу, которая по введенному значению аргумента вычисляет значение функции.

Tags: математика, pascal, график, c++, функции

Написать программу, которая по введенному значению аргумента вычисляет значение функции, заданной в виде графика. **Параметр R вводится с клавиатуры.**

Здравствуйте. Похоже что я немного туповат :(
В общем есть график функции и набор промежутков на нем. Собственно смущает параметр R. Ведь при изменении радиуса R функции на остальных промежутках тоже изменятся, из-за смещения окружности.
Помогите разобраться с промежутками и значением y.

Вот мои мысли по поводу промежутков:

```
 1.  x -> (-inf; -5-2R]: y = no solution;
 2. x -> (-5 - 2R; -R): y = 1 - sqrt(r^2-(x+7)); ?
 3. x -> (-5; -4]: y = 2; ?
 4. x -> [-4; 0]: y = (x + 4) * 0,5;
 5. x -> [0; Pi]: y = sin(x);
 6. x -> [Pi; 5]: y = x;
 7. x -> [5; +inf): y = no solution.
```

Очевидно что тут что-то не так...
[image]

Comment: Приведите код к читаемому виду. Для справки нажмите "вопрос" в меню редактирования.

Comment: Второй интервал `(-5 - 2R; -R)` странно выглядит. Может, верхняя граница всё-таки -5, а не -R? В этом случае при изменении R правый край окружности будет оставаться на месте, а сдвигаться будет только окружность.

Comment: Да, вы правы, верхняя граница -5.

Answer (score 1):

```
x -> [-4; 0]: y = x * (r/-4); /* x на тангенс угла */  
x -> [-5; -4]: y = R;
x -> [-5 - 2R; -5]: y = 1 - sqrt(r^2 - (x+7)^2)
```